# How do i import tables in big query?

Tags: sql, csv, import, google-bigquery, datatables

I have been trying to create tables by uploading/importing csv files to big query but the job never gets completed.
It says "Error while reading data, error message : csv encountered many errors"

I did not understand the error message.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8s2N.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)